# Can't access file via AJAX on host

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, localhost, mamp, http-status-code-403

I have a search function that calls a php-file ('live_search.php') via AJAX. So far so good.

There is an htaccess-file located in the same directory:

```
<FilesMatch "live_search.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from xx.xx.xxx.xxx 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Note: xx.xx.xxx.xxx is the 'IP'-address of my domain (I don't want to post the actual IP-address).

When I use MAMP (or XAMPP) it works on my local machine. But on my host (online) AJAX is not able to get access to that file ('403 forbidden').

How do I get access to the file on my host via AJAX?

Comment: why you want to access that file via ajax?

Comment: Because it's a search-function that delivers the results in real-time (like Google's search).

Comment: See it is request/response based application.You can achive this by making ajax call and find all the names of files matching the criteria and via ajax send those name back in response and show them to user as a real time search. Request/response based applications are different from desktop based application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on your local machine because you have `127.0.0.1`, which means if the request *comes from the 127.0.0.1 IP* (e.g. you are accessing it from your local machine) then allow the request. If you use that htaccess file on your host and you try to access the page, it's going to be your external IP, which isn't in the allow list, so you get a 403.

If you go to a service like this: http://www.whatismyip.com/ the IP address that they give you is going to be the one that is used to determine whether you can access the `live_search.php` file or not. And if the IP on that page isn't in the Allow list, you will get a 403. Anyone who tries to visit `live_search.php` who's IP isn't in your allow list will get a 403 result. Having the server's IP does absolutely nothing, except if someone has a browser open on the server and is browsing the page that makes the AJAX call.

Comment: So it would be better to allow access from all?

Comment: @drpelz If you want to allow anyone to access the search from AJAX, yes. Not sure what you're trying to achieve by denying access for everyone.

Comment: Thanks.:) I was just asking because of security reasons. Some people claimed you should avoid allowing access from anyone at all cost. But in my case I think I have no other choice. I edited my htaccess-file and now it works fine.